# Show trend arrows while displaying a dataframe

Tags: python, html, css, pandas, dataframe

I have a Pandas dataframe that is displayed like this in html:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
    [54, 21, 30, 12, '20-01-2002'],
    [52, 26, 31, 2, '22-01-2002'],
    [50, 16, 11, 15, '223-01-2002']
], columns=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'date']).transpose()
```

[image]

When rendering the dataframe as HTML, I need to display a trend icon (up or down arrow )on the first column  comparing it to the values in the 2nd column so the final html is rendered something like this:

[image]

First I thought it would be as easy as adding a span tag with the arrow to the  dataframe.

```
<span style="color:green;">&#x25B2;</span>   <!-- For Up Arrow -- > 
<span style="color:green;">&#x25BC;</span>    <!-- For Down Arrow -- >
```

So i tried adding that to the dataframe

```
df['A'] = df['A'].astype('str') + <span style="color:green;">&#x25B2;</span>
```

but when renderred as html, styler tries to escape the span tag and it is displayed as a text. I have tried using both `escape=''html` & `escape='latex'`

lated worked for span tag but still escapes the & with &

I am not very familiar with how styler works, so need help.

Comment: can you share some code please, i am not very familiar with pseudo selectors. Also , how would i attach those classes to the dataframe during render ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For an interactive display in a notebook, you can use:

```py
import numpy as np

UP = '<span style="color:green;">&#x25B2;</span>'
DOWN = '<span style="color:red;">&#x25BC;</span>'

# make copy to leave original dataframe unchanged
df2 = df.copy()

# select only relevant rows
idx = df.index!='date'

# convert to string and add arrow
df2.loc[idx, 0] = (df.loc[idx, 0].astype(str)
                  + np.where(df.loc[idx, 0].gt(df.loc[idx, 1]), UP, DOWN)
                   )

df2.style
```

For HTML export, use `escape=None`:

```py
df2.to_html(escape=None)
```

[image: pandas html format up down arrow]

For nothing on equality:

```
df2.loc[idx, 0] = (df.loc[idx, 0].astype(str) 
                   +np.sign(np.sign(df.loc[idx, 0].sub(df.loc[idx, 1]))
                           ).map({1:UP, -1:DOWN, 0:''})
                  )

df2.style
```

[image]

##### using CSS

Based on the answer of @mplungjan, here is an alternative using the HTML/CSS capabilities of the styler with [`style.set_td_classes`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.set_td_classes.html).

*NB. I formatted more cells here (each column relative to the next one) for the example:*

```
CSS = '''
<style>
.up::after {
  content: "▲";
  color: green;
}

.down::after {
  content: "▼";
  color: red;
}
</style>
'''

def arrow_up_down(df):
    return (np.sign(df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')
                      .diff(-1, axis=1))
              .replace({1:'up', -1:'down', 0: np.nan})
           )

from IPython.display import HTML
HTML(CSS+df.style.set_td_classes(arrow_up_down(df)).to_html())
```

output:

[image: pandas style CSS set_td_classes]

Comment: you can also add the pseudo selector as `pandas.set_table_styles`, then you do not have to import the iPython HTML class, it will be handled internally in pandas

Comment: @Attack68 would you kindly suggest an edit to the answer?

Answer (score 2):

Add two classes with pseudo selectors.

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/style.html#Table-styles

```css
.up::after {
  content: "▲";
  color: green;
}

.down::after {
  content: "▼";
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<table border="1" class="dataframe mystyle">
  <thead>
    <tr style="text-align: center;">
      <th></th>
      <th>date</th>
      <th>analysis_tool</th>
      <th>num1</th>
      <th>database</th>
      <th>num2</th>
      <th>os</th>
      <th>num3</th>
      <th>bool</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>0</th>
      <td>2018-04-21</td>
      <td>pandas</td>
      <td>153.474246</td>
      <td>mysql</td>
      <td class="up">0.658533</td>
      <td>ios</td>
      <td class="down">74</td>
      <td>True</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```